# Как привязать два поля в базе данных

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, проектирование

Имеется база для пользователей (родители и дети):

```
 - id пользователя
 - Фамилия
 - Имя
 - Номер телефона
 - Номер ребенка/родителя
 - Дата регистрации
```

И таблица координат:

```
 - Id координаты
 - Id пользователя
 - Широта
 - Долгота
 - Дата
```

Вот никак не могу понять как привязать родителя с ребенком, то есть регистрируется родитель, а потом ребенок. И в этом случае будут отправляться координаты ребенка родителю, а родителя ребенку. Я думаю создать еще одну таблицу для привязки, типа этого:

```
 - id родителя 
 - id ребенка
```

то есть, если родитель зарегистрировался и ввел номер ребенка, сюда вставляется его `ID`, а поле для `ID ребенка` будет пусто пока ребенок не зарегистрируется под своим номером и не совпадет его номер с тем, который ввел родитель. И наоборот если первым зарегался ребенок......

**Вопрос**: Будет ли правильно такая форма привязки или неправильно я все делаю, подскажите?

**UPD**: если неправильно сформулировал свои мысли, то к примеру могу привести соц. сети. Как пользователи отправляют запрос о дружбе другому пользователю и другой принимает дружбу? То есть что именно в базе происходит в этом случае?

Comment: Родитель один или два могут быть?

Comment: Потом Могут быть и два. Но пока только для одного

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов проектирования такой структуры может быть таким.

#### Структура таблиц

```
Пользователи
 - id пользователя
 - Фамилия
 - Имя
 - Номер телефона
 - Дата регистрации

Кординаты_пользователей
 - Id координаты
 - Id пользователя
 - Широта
 - Долгота
 - Дата

Родственные_отношения
 - пользователь_1
 - пользователь_2
 - тип отношения: отец, мать, сын, дочь, бабушка и т.п
 - дата запроса
 - дата ответа
 - статус запроса: в ожидании, отклонён, подтверждён
```

#### Случаи взаимодействия

Случай 1. Пользователь одиночка (родитель или ребёнок)

- Регистрируется пользователь А.
- Запись в Пользователи.

Случай 2. Пользователь родитель

- Регистрируется пользователь Б.
- Запись в Пользователи.
- Ищем номер Пользователя А (ребёнка).
- Проверяем наличие родственных связей.
- Если их нет, то посылаем запрос на подтверждение родственных связей.

  - Запись в Родственные_отношения кортежа: (Б, А, отец, дата запроса, null, в ожидании).
- Пользователь А получает и подтверждает запрос.

  - Обновление в Родственные_отношения кортежа: (Б, А, отец, дата запроса, дата ответа, подтверждён).

#### Взаимодействие с БД

При вышеупомянутой схеме отношение Родственные_отношения может выглядеть так (без дат и статуса):

```
Пользователь_1 | Пользователь_2 | Тип  |
===============|================|======|
Адам           | Каин           | отец |
Ева            | Авель          | мать |
Сиф            | Адам           | сын  |
Енос           | Сиф            | сын  |
```

Запросы на выборку детей может иметь такой вид:

```
SELECT Пользователь_1 FROM Родственные_отношения
WHERE 
  Пользователь_2 = "Адам" 
  Тип IN ("сын", "дочь")
UNION 
SELECT Пользователь_2 FROM Родственные_отношения
WHERE
  Пользователь_1 = "Адам" 
  Тип = "отец"
```

Comment: Извините, не совсем понял а номер ребенка/родителя в таблице пользователи не нужен, чтобы связать их?

Comment: @TITAN при данном подходе, да, не нужен. Все связи вынесены в отдельную таблицу.

Comment: Но мне именно нужно связать по номеру. А то для меня это слишком понять. Так как я ноль в SQL и вообще в веб разработке, поэтому выбрал самый быстрый вариант.

Comment: @TITAN вместо Пользователь_1 и Пользователь_2 просто указывайте номер: ID родителя и ребёнка. (Имена вместо номеров используются для наглядности)

Comment: То есть `Тип Отношений` можно удалить?

Comment: @TITAN нельзя..

Comment: Зачем мне если не буду их использовать. То есть два пользователя родитель и ребенок будут считаться просто двумя пользователями. У обоих будут одинаковые свойства